# hasMany relationship error in Swift using AWS Amplify generated code

Tags: swift, graphql, aws-amplify

My data model has a many to one relationship between the TICKETS table and the PLATES table. I built the model out using the AWS Amplify GUI and pulled down the source code generated into my Xcode project. For the relationships that exist in my data model, Xcode throws several errors on this line of the Swift schema file for the PLATES table:

```
model.fields(
      .id(),
      .field(pLATES.plateState, is: .optional, ofType: .string),
      .field(pLATES.plateNumber, is: .optional, ofType: .string),
      .field(pLATES.vehicleMake, is: .optional, ofType: .string),
      .field(pLATES.vehicleModel, is: .optional, ofType: .string),
      .field(pLATES.vehicleYear, is: .optional, ofType: .int),
      .field(pLATES.vehicleColor, is: .optional, ofType: .string),
      .hasMany(pLATES.TICKETS, is: .optional, ofType: TICKETS.self, associatedWith: TICKETS.keys.platesID),
      .field(pLATES.usersID, is: .optional, ofType: .string),
      .field(pLATES.createdAt, is: .optional, isReadOnly: true, ofType: .dateTime),
      .field(pLATES.updatedAt, is: .optional, isReadOnly: true, ofType: .dateTime)
    )
```

Errors all on the .hasMany line:

- Cannot convert value of type 'List?' to expected argument type 'Model.Type'
- Instance member 'TICKETS' cannot be used on type 'PLATES'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
- Value of type 'List?' has no member 'keys'

The GraphQL file on the backend appears to be structured correctly based on the Amplify documentation:

```
type TICKETS @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) @key(name: "byPLATES", fields: ["platesID"]) {
  id: ID!
  ticketID: Int
  reasonCode: Int
  ticketDateTime: AWSDateTime
  ticketLocationLong: Float
  ticketLocationLat: Float
  platesID: ID
  USERS: USERS @connection
}

type PLATES @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) @key(name: "byUSERS", fields: ["usersID"]) {
  id: ID!
  plateState: String
  plateNumber: String
  vehicleMake: String
  vehicleModel: String
  vehicleYear: Int
  vehicleColor: String
  TICKETS: [TICKETS] @connection(keyName: "byPLATES", fields: ["id"])
  usersID: ID
}
```

How can I remedy those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Is your relation between model bi-directional (do you use @belongsTo directive)?
If so, unfortunately  according to the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#belongs-to-relationship) this is not supported for iOS due to Swift.

> Bi-directional "has one" relationships currently cannot be represented on iOS due to Swift language limitations.

Hope it helps